# Representing flags of vector subbundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $F \to X$ be a free algebraic vector bundle of rank $n$. I know that there exists a correspondence between

- Vector subbundles $E \subset F$ of rank $k$.
- Morphisms $X \to G$, where $G$ is the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $\mathbb A^n$.

Now suppose that I am interested in

- Flags of vector subbundles $E_1 \subset ... \subset E_r \subset F$, where each $E_i$ is of rank $k_i$.

Is there a correspondence between these and

- Commutative diagrams of morphisms $X \to G_i$ and $G_i \to G_{i+1}$, where each $G_i$ is the Grassmannian of $k_i$-planes in $\mathbb A^n$

...?

Comment: $X$ is in fact a closed subscheme of $\prod G_i$, so you do have natural maps $X\to G_i$. There are no natural maps $G_i\to G_{i+1}$.

Comment: @Mohan: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by $X$ being a closed subscheme of $\prod_i G_i$. What would be the embedding? EDIT: Never mind. Maybe you mean that I should use a map $X \to H$, where $H$ is a closed subscheme of $\prod_i G_i$ that captures all the incidence relations?

Comment: @Mohan: As for there being no natural maps $G_i \to G_{i+1}$, that seems reasonable, since such a map would correspond to a global choice of a $k_{i+1}$-plane containing any $k_i$-plane. But then how do I represent the fact that my choice of $k_i$-plane has to be contained in the next $k_{i+1}$-plane?